# illegal 0000-00-00 00:00:00 timestamp being sent by php to mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, timestamp

here is a Database_update_entry function in my CodeIgniter model which gets executed upon successful form submission.

```
<?php
    function update_entry(){
        $data = array(
            'sl' => $this->input->post('item_sl'),
            'item_name' => $this->input->post('item_name'),
            'img_url' => $this->input->post('img_url'),
            'sound_url' => $this->input->post('sound_url'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
            'unit' => $this->input->post('unit'),
            'timestamp' => time(),
        );
        echo "current time: ".  time();
        $this->db->update(MY_TABLE_NAME, $data);
    }
?>
```

the database query gets executed fine.... but the time that gets set into the mysql table is 
**0000-00-00 00:00:00** whereas the `<?php echo time() ?>` statement shows **1307018223** in the browser.... which is a valid UNIX timestamp... you can [check the timestamp validity here](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

here is a screenshot of the table that takes data from mySQL table after successful update_queryhttp://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/658523?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1307020816&Signature=AncPjnzG9p9QTX7zebZp7c9teB0%3D

**what am i doing wrong??? how can i pass a legal timestamp from my php to mySQL?**
[p.s. i have checked that the timestamp field in my mysql table is a timestamp field]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mysql `timestamp` field accept `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s` format of date so you have to pass date into this format not the UNIX timestamp

instead of this

```
'timestamp' => time()
```

Use

```
'timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

If you really want to store `UNIX time stamp` change the field type to `CHAR`

Comment: @syedrakib: the CHAR(11) is okay for the timestamp field

Answer (score 3):

Use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());`

;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a time stamp string, not an integer. Try:

```
'timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
```

Comment: i thought mysql has its abilities of converting a UNIX timestamp to a mySQL timestamp if UNIX timestamp is added into the timestamp field

Answer (score 2):

format time : `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())`

Comment: i thought mysql has its abilities of converting a UNIX timestamp to a mySQL timestamp if UNIX timestamp is added into the timestamp field.... thanks :)